# Complex Query duplicating Result (same id, different columns values)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query, working great:

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
 select
        p.id,
        comparestrings('marco', pc.value) as similarity
 from
        unit u, person p
        inner join person_field pc ON (p.id = pc.id_person)
        inner join field c ON (pc.id_field = c.id AND c.flag_name = true)
     where  ( u.id = 1 ) AND p.id_unit = u.id    

 ) as subQuery
 where
        similarity is not null
        AND
        similarity > 0.35
 order by
        similarity desc;
```

Let me explain the situation.

TABLES:

- `person` ID as column.

  - `field` a table that represents a column, like `name, varchar` (something like that)
  - `person_field` represents the value of that person and that field.. Like this:
  - `unit` not relevant for this question

Eg.:

```
  Person id 1
  Field  id 1 {name, eg)
  value "Marco Noronha"
```

So the function "comparestrings" returns a double from 0 to 1, where 1 is exact ('Marco' == 'Marco').

So, I need all persons that have similarity above 0.35 and i also need its similarity.

No problem, the query works fine and as it was suppost to. But now I have a new requirement that, the table "person_field" will contain an alteration date, to keep track of the changes of those rows.

Eg.:

```
 Person ID 1 
 Field  ID 1 
 Value  "Marco Noronha"
 Date - 01/25/2013

 Person ID 1
 Field  ID 1
 Value  "Marco Tulio Jacovine Noronha"
 Date - 02/01/2013
```

So what I need to do, is consider ONLY the LATEST row!!
If I execute the same query  the result would be (eg):

```
 1, 0.8
 1, 0.751121
 2, 0.51212
 3, 0.42454
 //other results here, other 'person's
```

And lets supose that the value I want to bring is 1, 0.751121 (witch is the lattest value by DATE)

I think I should do something like  `order by date desc limit 1`...

But if I do something like that, the query will return only ONE person =/

Like:

```
 1, 0.751121
```

When I really want:

```
 1, 0.751121
 2, 0.51212
 3, 0.42454
```

Comment: I did, already. Is there something you didn´t understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON(p.id)` on the sub-query:

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
 select
        DISTINCT ON(p.id)
        p.id,
        comparestrings('marco', pc.value) as similarity
 from
        unit u, person p
        inner join person_field pc ON (p.id = pc.id_person)
        inner join field c ON (pc.id_field = c.id AND c.flag_name = true)
     where  ( u.id = 1 ) AND p.id_unit = u.id    
     ORDER BY p.id, pc.alt_date DESC

 ) as subQuery
 where
        similarity is not null
        AND
        similarity > 0.35
 order by
        similarity desc;
```

Notice that, to make it work I needed to add `ORDER BY p.id, pc.alt_date DESC`:

- `p.id`: required by `DISTINCT ON` (if you use `ORDER BY`, the first fields must be exactly the same as `DISTINCT ON`);
- `pc.alt_date DESC`: the alter date you mentioned (we order desc, so we get the oldest ones by each `p.id`)

By the way, seems that you don't need a sub-query at all (just make sure `comparestrings` is marked as `stable` or `immutable`, and it'll be fast enough):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON(p.id)
    p.id,
    comparestrings('marco', pc.value) as similarity
FROM
    unit u, person p
    inner join person_field pc ON (p.id = pc.id_person)
    inner join field c ON (pc.id_field = c.id AND c.flag_name = true)
WHERE  ( u.id = 1 ) AND p.id_unit = u.id    
    AND COALESCE(comparestrings('marco', pc.value), 0.0) > 0.35
ORDER BY p.id, pc.alt_date DESC, similarity DESC;
```

Comment: Matheus, I can´t execute the compareString function twice at the database, because I have =~  22kk rows on "person_field" table. :(

Comment: Ops, didn´t read your answer currectly. Thanks man, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Change the reference to `person` to a subquery as in the following example (the subquery is the one called `p`):

```
. . .
from unit u cross join
     (select p.*
      from (select p.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by person_id order by alterationdate desc) as seqnum
            from person p
           ) p
      where seqnum = 1
     ) p
     . . .
```

This uses the `row_number()` function to identify the last row.  I've used an additional subquery to limit the result just to the most recent.  You could also include this in an `on` clause or a `where` clause.

I also changed the `,` to an explicit `cross join`.

Comment: Wow, I didn´t understand. why are you selecting UNIT ? I need to select person_id and similarity. Unit is just a where clause because the person has an attribute 'id_unit' and I need to filter it by unit . Can you help me further more? thanks!

Comment: @d34d_d3v1l . . . I was just showing where you would replace the code.